# Get the division class object on button click using html and javascript to change the header of the division class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="job0">
        <b>
            <h3 id="Name0" >fg</h3>
        </b>
        <button type="button" id="options0" style="display:none;" onclick="someFunction(this.class)" ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="job1">
        <b>
            <h3 id="Name1">dfdf</h3>
        </b>
        <button type="button" id="options1" style="display:none;"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="job2">
        <b>
            <h3 id="Name2">dfdf</h3>
        </b>
        <progress id="lineCoverage2" max="100" style="display:none;"></progress>
        <button type="button" id="options2" style="display:none;" ></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are three grids, when i click on any button on any of these three grids the header value of that particular grid must be displayed on alert box for this I need the `div` class object, can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Please update the question with relevant html and js code

Comment: i don't know how write js code for this ....  that is what i wanted to know ,thanks for the reply

Comment: did you understand the question ?? i am loading data in those grids ,if anyone know how to automate that code for creating grids dynamically please inform that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jQuery in your page and use the following code block

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').on('click', function() {
         alert($(this).closest('div').find('h3').text());
     });
 });
```

BTW I am not sure why the buttons are hidden on your HTML

Comment: thanks a lot ,but do you know how to dynamically generate that code?? using javascript??

Comment: You can dynamically create the div using jQuery and attach the necessary data to it. Its better to use a templating engine like Handlebars for this purpose.

Comment: can you give me the reference please ...add $(:button) to the answer

Comment: http://marcgrabanski.com/building-html-in-jquery-and-javascript/ , please let me know why $(':button') is required

Comment: without that also it works,i had mistake so it was giving me problem,thanks a lot man